Best approach to filter a Map to an Object in JS?
I have a Map and I want to convert it to an Object filtering out entries that don't meet some condition.
My first solution was:


let m = new Map([
    ["key1", { flag: true}],
    ["key2", { flag: false}]
])

o = Object.fromEntries(m.entries()
    .filter(([k,v]) => v.flag)
    .map(([k,v]) => [k, true]));
console.log(o)



However it appears that iterator.filter is not generally available. So I came up with this alternative:


let m = new Map([
    ["key1", { flag: true}],
    ["key2", { flag: false}]
])

let o = Object.fromEntries(
    Array.from(m.entries())
    .map(([k,v]) => [k, v.flag])
    .filter(v => v[1]));

console.log(o)



Which I think is better supported.
Is there a better / faster solution? If iterator.filter was widely supported, would the first solution be a good solution?

i would filter first and then map ...

btw, o (first example) is global.

"Is there a better / faster solution": "better" is not well defined, and several things that might be thought of as better are a matter of opinion and off topic here. *"would the first solution be a good solution?": that depends on what someone considers good. This is a matter of opinion, which is off topic here.

Array.from(m).map(f) is the unenlightened way to write Array.from(m,f), which does the same thing in half the work.

For the example, a Set would maybe be more appropriate as output.

A more browser-friendly option that doesn't rely on the new iterator methods is to use a for..of loop and perform the mapping and the filtering in each iteration, for example:


let m = new Map([
    ["key1", { flag: true}],
    ["key2", { flag: false}]
]);

const o = Object.create(null);
for (const [k, v] of m) {
  if (v.flag)
    o[k] = true;
}
console.log(o);



If you want to stick with using Object.fromEntries(), you can consider making your own map and filter generators that accept an iterable, that way you avoid doing the additional iteration through your iterator to convert it into an array:


let m = new Map([
    ["key1", { flag: true}],
    ["key2", { flag: false}]
]);

function* filter(itr, pred) {
  for (const elem of itr) {
    if (pred(elem))
      yield elem;
  }
}

function* map(itr, mapper) {
  for (const elem of itr) {
    yield mapper(elem);
  }
}

const o = Object.fromEntries(map(
  filter(m.entries(), ([k,v]) => v.flag), 
  ([k,v]) => [k, true])
);
console.log(o);




Your first solution is much more readable and obvious. I'm new to JS and getting bound up in trying to do it the modern JS way instead of the straight forward way, and based on below it's pretty fast. Thanks

If you avoid creating intermediate arrays you could do it faster:
` Chrome/125
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                    n=10       |       n=100       |      n=1000      |     n=10000    
for..in         ■ 1.00x x1m 111 | ■ 1.00x x100k 187 | ■ 1.00x x10k 162 | ■ 1.00x x1k 269
keys + reduce     1.04x x1m 115 |   1.08x x100k 202 |   1.28x x10k 208 |   1.64x x1k 441
OP                5.21x x1m 578 |   2.44x x100k 457 |   3.99x x10k 647 |   3.54x x1k 953
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- `
` Firefox/126
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                    n=10       |       n=100       |      n=1000      |     n=10000     
for..in           1.09x x1m 259 |   1.13x x100k 239 |   1.04x x10k 299 | ■ 1.00x  x1k 538
keys + reduce   ■ 1.00x x1m 238 | ■ 1.00x x100k 212 | ■ 1.00x x10k 288 |   1.33x  x1k 715
OP                2.05x x1m 487 |   2.32x x100k 491 |   1.89x x10k 544 |   1.78x x100  96
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- `

Open in the playground


let $length = 10;
const m = Array.from({length: $length}).reduce((r, _, i) => (r.set('key'+ (i + 1), {flag: Math.random() > .5}), r), new Map);

// @benchmark OP
Object.fromEntries(
    Array.from(m.entries())
    .map(([k,v]) => [k, v.flag])
    .filter(v => v[1]));

// @benchmark for..in
const obj = {}
for (const [k, v] of m) v.flag && (obj[k] = true);
obj;


// @benchmark keys + reduce
[...m.keys()].reduce((r, key) => (m.get(key).flag && (r[key] = true), r), {});

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));




Nice to see the numbers. I shall have to book mark the playground and learn to use it
